# Uncaught TypeError: WeakMap is not a constructor when using react-quill-with-table in a Laravel React Inertia.js application

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs, react-quill

I'm working on a Laravel application with React and Inertia.js, and I'm trying to integrate the react-quill-with-table project to handle rich text editing with tables. While everything works as expected in my development environment, I'm encountering the following error when deploying the application in a production environment:

[image]

This error is preventing the application from functioning correctly in production. I've tried various solutions I found online, but the issue persists. Can anyone provide insights into what's causing this error and how to resolve it within the context of a Laravel React Inertia.js application?

Here's a relevant code snippet where I'm using react-quill-with-table within a component:

```
"react-quill-with-table": "^1.3.3"
```

Please feel free to share any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue within a Laravel React Inertia.js application.

Comment: The error "WeakMap is not a constructor" suggests that the JavaScript engine in your production environment doesn't support the ```WeakMap``` object, which is a part of the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) specification. This issue might be due to the fact that your production environment is running an older version of Node.js or a JavaScript engine that doesn't fully support ES6. Update to latest might solve your problem.